# Disabling onclick() after 1 click

Tags: javascript

I am having a little trouble with a JS event. I have an  link that calls the onclick event which opens up a photo in a popup modal window - facebox.

When the user single clicks on the link the image file name attached to that link is passed to the modal window, however if the user double clicks the image file opens twice in the modal window.

I have tried a simple ondblclick="" and ondblclick="return false" to stop this but it seems the browser still interprets it as 2 single onclick() events.

Can anyone suggest a fix or a solution whereby the  link is temporarily disabled after the 1st click?

Here is the code below that is calling the event:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="setVisibility(\'deletephotodiv'.$do.'\', \'block\');" onmouseout="setVisibility(\'deletephotodiv'.$do.'\', \'none\');" ondblclick="parent.jQuery.facebox({ ajax: \'profile/previewphoto.inc.php?photo=',$_SESSION['images'][$do]['name'],'&album=',$_SESSION['images'][$do]['albumname'],'\' }); ">
```

Thanks in advance

Wayne

Comment: How about checking whether the window is opened? Onclick event is synchronous, so the window object should be there upon 2nd click.

Comment: Why isn't the modal window's background preventing the second click like it does in all the examples on [http://defunkt.io/facebox/](this) page?

Comment: Interesting, how would i do that?

Answer (score 2):

see jQuery unbind .
http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

or use a boolean variable to return from your functions.
Set it as True for first click, on next  clicks, the function would just return as the variable would have been set to true.
eg

```
var firstDone = false;
function myClickHandler()
{
   if(firstDone === true)
         return;
   /* here is some work */
   alert(123);
   firstDone = true ;
}
```

Comment: jQuery is mentioned nowhere actually. However, even with jQuery this is way too complicated.

Comment: But this would make the link unclickable, which is not what he wants. He wants the link to be clickable forever, but not when the modal window is active.

Comment: @jAndy: "parent.jQuery.facebox"?

Comment: @jandy, he is indeed using jQuery, I really feel sad when instead of RTFM-ing and putting some efforts people turn to easy help

Comment: @pyvi: doh well, my bad. I didn't scroll to the right far enough I guess ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you may also consider `http://api.jquery.com/one/` and when you are onto using jQuery please avoid writing code like `onmouseover`, use jquery to full and bind events to the hyperlink and do provide some hyperlink to href instead of `javascript:void(0);`